# Passing parameters one by one, or by wrapping them in an array, struct or tuple

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, calling-convention

When passing arguments to a function I always assumed that passing arguments one by one is not different from passing them wrapped in an array or a struct or a tuple. However, a simple experiment showed that I was wrong.

The following program when [compiled with GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8ada7a7155b601d):

```
int test(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return a + b + c + d;
}

int test(std::array<int, 4> arr) {
    return arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
}

struct abcd {
    int a; int b; int c; int d;
};

int test(abcd s) {
    return s.a + s.b + s.c + s.d;
}

int test(std::tuple<int, int, int, int> tup) {
    return std::get<0>(tup) + std::get<1>(tup) + std::get<2>(tup) + std::get<3>(tup);
}
```

...produces a variety of assembly outputs:

```
impl_test(int, int, int, int):
    lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
    add eax, edx
    add eax, ecx
    ret

impl_test(std::array<int, 4ul>):
    mov rax, rdi
    sar rax, 32
    add eax, edi
    add eax, esi
    sar rsi, 32
    add eax, esi
    ret

impl_test(abcd):
    mov rax, rdi
    sar rax, 32
    add eax, edi
    add eax, esi
    sar rsi, 32
    add eax, esi
    ret

impl_test(std::tuple<int, int, int, int>):
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+8]
    add eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+12]
    add eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+4]
    add eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    ret

main:
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    mov ecx, 4
    mov edx, 3
    movabs  rbp, 8589934592
    mov esi, 2
    sub rsp, 24
    mov edi, 1
    movabs  rbx, 17179869184
    call    int test<int, int, int, int>(int, int, int, int)

    mov rdi, rbp
    mov rsi, rbx
    or  rbx, 3
    or  rdi, 1
    or  rsi, 3
    call    int test<std::array<int, 4ul> >(std::array<int, 4ul>)

    mov rdi, rbp
    mov rsi, rbx
    or  rdi, 1
    call    int test<abcd>(abcd)

    mov rdi, rsp
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp], 4
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+4], 3
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+8], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 1
    call    int test<std::tuple<int, int, int, int> >(std::tuple<int, int, int, int>)

    add rsp, 24
    xor eax, eax
    pop rbx
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Why is there a difference?

Comment: Can't compilers generally do whatever they want as long as the end result is the same?

Comment: @AndyG Yes and no.  There are also calling conventions based on both language and platform that dictate how things are called.  Without such things (like arguments passed in registers from right to left) it would be impossible to link various object files together from different source languages and produce reliable code.

Comment: The struct *is* being passed as if the individual members were separate. But the optimizer (or lack of) is doing something weird with the 64-bit down-conversion to 32-bit.

Comment: @Cicada: That was me being a little tongue in cheek. Sort of an exasperated "I don't know!" to StackedCrooked's question :-)

Comment: @imreal When compiling object files, the location of the parameters needs to strictly follow the calling convention. So compiler can't "do whatever it wants" unless it inlines. But in this case, the OP isn't testing the inlining case.

Comment: This depends on the ABI. [This](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) says that arguments are passed in separate registers, so the first one with four `int` arguments uses four registers. The `std::array` and `abcd` are trivially copyable and small enough to be passed by register, but they are packed into two registers. The `tuple` appears to be passed in memory, but I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: With a few arguments, the situation is complicated.  I'd be interested to see what happens if you tried it with, say, 50 arguments.  I'm guessing that the resultant code wont vary so much.

Answer (score 2):

When a function is called (that is, not inlined, `constexpr` evaluated or eliminated), the way arguments are passed depends on many factors including:

- Whether the argument is an integer or floating-point if the argument is of a primitive type.
- The type of the argument.
- Whether its address is taken in some non-eliminated code in the callee.
- The default or specified calling convention.
- Whether Whole Program Optimization (WPO) is being used.
- Whether the callee is in a shared library, static library or object file, or in the same translation unit.
- The specified floating-point behavior.
- The target platform.
- The position of the parameter in the parameter list.

Let's get back to the example you provided. You compiled the code with `-02` so dead code won't be eliminated and function inlining is disabled. So all functions have to be called. The target platform is x64.

The first function has four 4-byte integer parameters. Therefore, all of them are passed through registers.

The second function has one fixed-size array of four 4-byte integers. The compiler decided to use two registers (`rdi` and `rsi`) to pass the four integers where `rdi` = 0x200000001 and `rsi` = 0x400000003. Notice how the four integers (1, 2, 3, 4) are compactly passed using these two registers.

Passing the integers as a structure rather then one by one made the compiler use different techniques to pass them. But there is a trade off here between the size of code, speed and number of registers required.

The same thing goes for the third function.

The last function, however, contains calls to `std::get` which require the address of the passed tuple. So the address is stored in `rdi` to be used by the `std::get` function. Since you're compiling with C++14, std::get is marked with `constexpr`. The compiler was able to evaluate the function and therefore the memory access has been emitted in test function rather than emitting a call to the `std::get` function. Notice that this is different from inlining.